# Reset / Reinstall "App installer"

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

On my Windows 10 Pro machine (1709), double-clicking an `.appxbundle` will start the App Installer but directly show the following error message:

[image: The remote procedure call failed]

The `Apps` event log shows the following entry:

> Activation for Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed. Error code: The remote procedure call failed.. Activation phase: COM App activation

I removed the installer app (via `Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.0.12894.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`) and installed it again from the Store, but the error still occurs. The error is not related to the AppXBundle being installed (VCLibs will fail as well, the same package can be installed on other machines).

Installing bundles via PowerShell or the device portal works as expected.

So how to repair or reset the App Installer on Windows 10 (or further trace the issue down)?

Comment: [activate developer portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-desktop) and deploy the app from the browser (127.0.0.1 ). does this work?

Comment: If you are using a Enterprise version of Windows 10 edit and update your question

Comment: @magicandre1981: Sorry, I should have mentioned that installing bundles via PowerShell (or the portal) works, so this issue is just related to the "App Installer" app. Updated the question.

Comment: I have no idea why this fails. use device portal workaround and try again next month after Microsoft released Windows 10 1803. Maybe the issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to Windows 10 1809, the App Installers works once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Type Services into the Start menu search box.
2. In Services, scroll down to "Remote Procedure Call", make sure the
   status says "Started" and set to Automatic.
3. The second "RPC Locator" should be set to "Manual".
4. Then try the PowerShell command to register the configuration files:

   `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Comment: Thanks Karen. The services are configured as mentioned. The PowerShell command did reinstall the app but the error remains the same.

Comment: Which .appxbundle? was it your customized app? what if it on other windows 10 computer?

Comment: An inhouse app, yes. But it doesn't matter which bundle (VCLibs fail as well). Works well on other computers. And works well via PowerShell. Therefore, I assume the "App Installer" app just fails to start (as stated by the event log message).